# Is there a way to find out SSD page size on Linux/Unix? What is "physical block" in fdisk output?

Tags: ssd

Everywhere I read that internally SSDs are structured in 4K or larger "pages", which grouped in "blocks" of about 128-256 pages ([1](https://www.extremetech.com/extreme/210492-extremetech-explains-how-do-ssds-work), [2](http://codecapsule.com/2014/02/12/coding-for-ssds-part-2-architecture-of-an-ssd-and-benchmarking/)). SSDs work with these pages and blocks, "they can only erase data at the block level" (thus the block of pages is called "[NAND] erase block"). And the 512B blocks for the partition are emulated (which is done for legacy reasons).

I'm trying to get educated on SSDs, since I have some weird lags/freezes during writes to my Sandisk U100 on Samsung 9 np900x3c laptop.
And one useful thing would be to correctly find out what pages/blocks my SSD has?

**Is there a utility or `/sys/...` file on Linux to determine the SSD page size?**

Or "the drive and Googling the part numbers on the NAND chips may be needed", as in [the comment](https://superuser.com/questions/728858/how-to-determine-ssds-nand-erase-block-size#comment934694_728858)?

Googling my Sandisk SSD I cannot find a proper datasheet/spec.
But [Sandisk](https://www.csi.pl/images/product/u100_ssd_product%20brochure.pdf) and [people](https://www.cnet.com/products/sandisk-ssd-u100-solid-state-drive-128-gb-sata-6gb-s/specs/) do mention "4K random reads/writes".
Does it mean the disk has 4K pages?

Also, `fdisk` shows me sector size (both physical and logical) and I/O 512 byte:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 128.0 GB, 128035676160 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 15566 cylinders, total 250069680 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x4b914713

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048    50331647    25164800   83  Linux
/dev/sda2        50331648   239583231    94625792   83  Linux
/dev/sda4       239583232   250068991     5242880   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

What is "physical" sector size here? It doesn't seem to be the parameter of the SSD drive itself, since everybody say SSD pages are 4K+. Is it the emulated parameter for the disk? And "logical" is the sector size for the partition?
Also, what is I/O size?

PS

This question is probably the same as [this one for USB flash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213387/how-to-find-the-page-size-of-physical-memories-from-userspace) -- the answer is missing the point there, `man fsstat` says `fsstat  displays  the  details  associated with a file system` and the question is about the disk itself. My post has more details, maybe it would attract better responses?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

- The physical block size reported by `fdisk` is the physical block size reported by the disk when asked. It seldom has any relationship with SSD pages or erase blocks.
- 4 KiB reads/writes are a common measure of I/O performance, representing "small" I/O operations.
- There is no standard way for a SSD to report its page size or erase block size. Few if any manufacturers report them in the datasheets. (Because they may change during the lifetime of a SKU, for example because of changing suppliers.) There is a [whitepaper from Intel](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/ssd-server-storage-applications-paper.pdf) which suggests that 4 KiB alignment is enough.
- For practical use just align all your data structures (partitions, payload of LUKS containers, LVM logical volumes) to 1 or 2 MiB boundaries. It's an SSD after all--it is designed to cope with usual filesystems, such as NTFS (which uses 4 KiB allocation units). If Windows considers that aligning partitions to 1 MiB is enough you can bet that any SSD manufacturer will make sure that their products work well with such a configuration.
- Best leave about 5% to 10% of unallocated space outside any partitions. Having overprovisioned space is of great help to SSDs in maintaining their performance in time.

Comment: "There is a whitepaper from Intel which suggests that 4 KiB alignment is enough." How do you get that from the linked paper? I looked over it, and it isn't at all obvious where the paper is claiming that.

Comment: @Matthew: Page 7: *"most new HDDs and Intel SSDs perform better with a 4096 Byte (4KB) alignment"*.

Comment: I read that as "compared to 512 bytes", which is hardly surprising. Additionally, the following figures seem to imply a 4KiB page size. I don't read that as implying that "4KiB is good enough for drives with pages > 4KiB"... or that it's meant to say *anything* about non-Intel drives.

Comment: +1 for sticking strictly to the KiB/MiB notation --- see `man units` for the sceptics

Comment: Why is _Having overprovisioned space ... of great help to SSDs in maintaining their performance in time_?

Comment: @XavierStuvw: Because it will leave a number of blocks on the "never touched by the OS" list. This will simplify the life of the microcontroller which needs to juggle block allocations and erasures; remember that the poor little microcontroller has no notion of file systems, and from its point of view all the blocks touched by the operating system are in use, unless of course the OS is kind enough to trim unused blocks from time to time. This is especially important for external SSDs, which quite often may not even expose a trim interface.

Comment: OK, but what is the purpose of having a number of blocks on a list never to be touched? Isn't it the blocks' own purpose to be used by an OS? In other words, what is wrong with contiguous partitions? Thanks by the way for the quick reply.

Comment: @XavierStuvw: There is no relationship between the linear array of blocks seen by the OS and the real physical blocks on the SSD. Remember that SSDs cannot overwrite blocks individually. When the OS updates a "logical" block, the microcontroller must find a new unused block, copy the updated data to that block, and move the old block in the "blocks to be erased and recycled" list. SSDs cannot even erase individual blocks, so at a certain point the microcontroller will have to allocate a new page, move some blocks and erase the old page. Having spare blocks *known* to be not used helps.

Comment: @XavierStuvw: In other words: the microcontroller maintains a mapping between the physical blocks on the SSD and the logical blocks presented to the OS. It must perform quite complicated housekeeping activities to spread writes so that all physical blocks are used uniformly.

Comment: OK thanks, so the microcontroller has more space to move around stuff coming from within the partitions, without touching the interior of the partitions in the intermediate stages. This sounds also like a guarantee against overwriting mistakes. My two cents. Your explanation has been useful to educate my intuition a step further. Thx

Comment: @XavierStuvw : sorry to jump on this over 3 years late, but when you say " remember that the poor little microcontroller has no notion of file systems" do you imply that it *does* have notion of the partition table? Otherwise how would it know which portion of the disk is never going to be used ("never" meaning until the thing is repartitioned I presume)?

Comment: @RJVB: The controller maps logical pages to physical pages. It keeps a list of free physical pages. It knows nothing of partitition tables, file systems and so on. It just knows what pages have been written to and what pages have not been written to. It doesn't know that a logical page will never be used in the future; but it does know that it has never been used in the past since the last clean up. This allows it to use the corresponding physical page when it needs a fresh logical page. (And it will clean up dirty pages which are no longer needed and place them on the free list.)

Comment: OK, thanks, but so what constitutes a "clean up" from the controller's point of view? It'd be annoying if you keep a partition offline after formatting and possibly storing some things on it, and then find out that it's no longer intact if you try to access it in some suitably distant future!

Comment: @RJVB: Clean up means erase. None of this is visible to the operating system. That is the point. A modern OS expects to be able to overwrite a disk block with new data, but flash memory cannot be modified once written, except that an entire erase page can be erased and new data written to it. An erase page is 1 megabyte or so, way too large for the OS to use erase pages as disk blocks. In order to make flash memory behave like a disk from the point of view of the OS, the flash controller makes this physical-to-logical mapping and juggling of data copying, page erasing, and block remapping.

Answer (score 7):

I have tested misreporting SSDs by looking at
SMART attribute 241 Total_LBAs_Written.

**Warning: the following command will corrupt your data:** 
And then `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/ssd_drive bs=1 count=1`
(need to do it without filesystem overhead).

For a Samsung 850 EVO which reports 512 as sector size,
the count increased by 8 with only one byte written.

So 8×512=4096 , and writing `bs=4096` also increases by 8.

Meaning drive will always write to 4096-byte sectors internally.

Comment: That looks like a clever approach, but the Sandisk SSD I have at hand reports attr. 241 as "Host_Writes_32MiB" which suggests an unlikely high page size. There's also 245 "TLC_Writes_32MiB", btw.

Comment: In fact, can't you use `hdparm`, to write 1 *sector*? That should write the physical sector size, with the advantage that you can control where the write takes places, e.g. in a non-allocated part if you don't want to lose any data.

Answer (score 1):

`smartctl` (available in `smartmontools`) should do it for you.

Comment: How would the OP use this tool to do so?

Comment: for now I'm getting the same 512B physical & logical sectors with `smartctl -i /dev/sda`, not sure how to read `smartctl --all /dev/sda` and `smartctl --xall /dev/sda` sent kernel into panic..

Comment: Having [read up](http://www.linuxjournal.com/magazine/monitoring-hard-disks-smart) on [SMART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.), I think it doesn't address such information as SSDs internal structure -- it monitors some parameters on errors/"health" of a disk, trying to catch possibility of disk failure